# Show that the codimension of the following variety is at least 2.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $Y:=Z(xw-yz) \subset \mathbf{A}_k^4$ and let $U:= Y\setminus Z(x,y)$.

> Show that if $V \subset \mathbf{A}_k^4$ is an open set in the zariski topology such that $V \cap Y = U$, and $Z = \mathbf{A}_k^4 \setminus V$ is its complement, then $\text{codim}_{\mathbf{A}_k^4} Z \ge 2.$

What I've tried so far is

> $V \cap Y = (\mathbf{A}_k^4 \setminus Z) \cap Y = Y \setminus (Y \cap Z) = Y \setminus Z(x,y).$
> So $Y \cap Z = Z(xw-yz) \cap Z = Z(x,y).$
> It suffices to show that $\text{codim}_{\mathbf{A}_k^4} Z \neq 0,1.$
> Clearly, it cannot be $0$, since $\mathbf{A}_k^4$ is the only variety of codimension $0$.
> So assume that $\text{codim}_{\mathbf{A}_k^4} Z = 1$ to derive a contradiction. 
> If we write $Z = Z(I)$ for some radical ideal $I$, then there exists a chain of ideals
> $$(0) \subsetneq \mathfrak{p} \subset I \subsetneq (x,y),$$
> where $(0), \mathfrak{p}, (x,y)$ are all prime ideals in $k[x,y,z,w]$.
> And $k[x,y,z,w]$ is a UFD, so $\mathfrak{p} = (f)$ for some irreducible $f$.
> $f = ax+by$ for some $a,b \in k[x,y,z,w]$. 
> $Z(x,y) \subsetneq Z(f)$ implies that there is a point $(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbf{A}_k^4$ such that $f(x,y,z,w) =0$ with either $x \neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$.

So far I didn't use the assumption of codimension $1$. But I don't see how to apply it.
Could you give me a hint to proceed by myself?

Comment: Why is your prime ideal $p$ principal?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg p is a height 1 of prime ideal in a UFD. So it is principal, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the solution. Here it is.

If we could write $Z(x,y) = Y \cap Z$ for some hypersurface $Z$, 
then there would be another hypersurface $Z'$ such thath $Z(z,w) = Y \cap Z'$.
And we use the following result

> If $Y$ is an affine variety of dimension $r$ and $Z$ a hypersurface,
> then either $Y \subset Z$ or every irreducible component of $Y \cap Z$ is of dimension $r-1$.

It is clear that $Y \not\subset Z$, so any irreducible component of $Y\cap Z$, which is equal to $Z(x,y)$, is of $\operatorname{dim}(Y)-1 = \text{dimension }2$. 
Similar arguments shows that $\operatorname{dim}Z(x,y,z,w) =\operatorname{dim}(Y \cap Z \cap Z') = 1$.
But $\operatorname{dim}Z(x,y,z,w) =0$, which is a contradction we're looking for.